# MVVM for WPF with extension methods, without DataBinding! Why not?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

Let's say I have the following XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Canvas>
    <Button Content="Write something" Canvas.Left="43" Canvas.Top="159" Width="162" Height="42" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
</Canvas>
```

My ViewModel can be this class, or can contain a instance of it (a viewmodel logic) :

```
 //Here is my static class for extension methods
 public static  class ExtendenWindowClass
{

  /// <summary>
  /// Eventhandler for Button
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="obj"></param>
  /// <param name="sender"></param>
  /// <param name="e"></param>
  public static void Button_Click_1(this MainWindow obj, object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {

      MessageBox.Show("Wait 10 seconds");
      Thread.Sleep(10000);
      MessageBox.Show("Ready, now you can press again");
  }
}
```

So the whiring is no longer in code behind, but in an extension method. The usage of static fields for MainWindow class is minimal, so it can be skipped.

The look of xaml is more natural than with DataBinding objects and curly braces. And I also follow separation of concepts .
  What do you think ?

Comment: MVVM is about avoiding any reference to View. This extended class still references Window.

Comment: This is more of an answer than a comment. Verry interesting!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just doing it other way around.

There are `multiple ways of extending a class`. Two of them are -

1. Partial class.
2. Extension methods.

In `code behind` you are extending your class using `partial class` implementation.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window { }
```

And in code you posted you are achieving that using other way i.e. extension methods. I don't think this way you are getting something more here.

---

MVVM pattern's main motive is to `decouple UI logic from business logic`. Also having code in extension method OR in code behind can't be `unit tested` at all. Code behind and having extension method on window is exactly same for me. Your `View and ViewModel should work oblivious to each other` so that it can be worked on simultaneously by different developers.

You can read about MVVM more [here](http://wpftutorial.net/MVVM.html) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Comment: Hi! Your answer does not reflect the nature of MVVM. You haven't answered with respect of best practice (choose between DataBinding and extension methods). I know the possibility of extending a class through .Net. I am expecting from you to tell me, Why should I use DataBinding in a pure MVVM patern instead of extension methods. And why are extension methods not desirable in MVVM. You know.... the properties binding....right??!!

Comment: Hope it makes sense now.